# Filtering values from OLAP Cube Pivot Table

Tags: vba, filtering, pivot-table, excel-2013, olap-cube

I have a pivot table with a lots of date that I can choose in the filter (more than 1000 differents values).
What I need is to filter these values which are Dates from a user input.
example: Start date is 01-03-2018 to End date 20-03-2018

I need to do this through VBA code.

I'm not sure if actually the date values shown in the PT are really declared as date variable.
These values come from the Time dimension of the cube.
Here are some screenshots.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giTT5.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLkT6.png)

I made a try by using Wroksheet_Change but that works fine when I enter one date only (for example 2018-03-20) and the PT updates correctly, but i don´t know how to do it for a range of dates. Here is the code I used for one date only

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim newDate As String
newDate = Worksheets("KPICuboSIGP").Range("M4").Value

If Target.Address = "$M$4" Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("KPI-BPOP").PivotFields("[Time].[Date].[Date]"). _
        VisibleItemsList = Array("[Time].[Date].&[" & newDate & "T00:00:00]")
        End If
End Sub
```

I turned on the macro recorder too, and this is what it recorded.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("KPI-BPOP").PivotFields("[Time].[Date].[Date]"). _
        VisibleItemsList = Array("[Time].[Date].&[2018-01-21T00:00:00]", _
        "[Time].[Date].&[2018-01-22T00:00:00]", "[Time].[Date].&[2018-01-23T00:00:00]", _
        "[Time].[Date].&[2018-01-24T00:00:00]", "[Time].[Date].&[2018-01-25T00:00:00]", _
        "[Time].[Date].&[2018-01-26T00:00:00]")
```

Those dates recorded should be selected automatically once I have the range from the user. Maybe I need to cycle through the options in the filter with For cycle, but I don´t know how to do it.
I'm pretty much a rookie in VBA

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You can use the Labels filter to accomplish this. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556897/use-vba-to-select-and-deselect-multiple-slicer-items-olap-data/49619983#49619983

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Labels filter to accomplish this. The problem is that the Labels filter isn't available to fields in the Filters part of a PivotTable. So you need to whip up a second PivotTable with nothing but the Dates field in it as a row field, then connect that PivotTable to the original PivotTable with a Slicer, and then programatically set a Label filter on the second PivotTable as I outline at [Use VBA to select and deselect multiple slicer items (OLAP data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556897/use-vba-to-select-and-deselect-multiple-slicer-items-olap-data/49619983#49619983)

Comment: I've already tried to use label filters before but somehow I cannot get the range working and filtering isn't working too.
I've tried many combinations for dates to filter in these labels but nothing works. It seems the date format is kind of ambiguous, because i don´t know how it was declared

You can see in image 1 that date says "Sunday, January 21 2018" even writing that in the filters doesn't work at all.

Maybe someone knows how that kind of date can be filtered by label filters or how to write the correct format to filter.